# How to refresh the python IDLE screen on Windows?

Tags: python-idle

I couldn't find any button on it which let me refresh the screen without lose the current data. Like `ctrl + L` do in Linux.

How to do that?

Comment: I only use Windows.  'Modem noise', 'broadcast messages', and terminal emulation screwups seem to be specific to linux or X11.  Tkinter and hence Idle do not have a 'refresh' method.  Does minimize and restore work?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, that didn't work, apparently. But I found a compensate plan, that is to decrease the height of IDLE window, and focus my eye on the bottom, though not good enough.